# SQL - Query Non-existent records come NULL

Tags: sql-server

I want the records to come in without my question.
Please help me. Thank you now.

```
SELECT 
    ROUTE_ID,
    ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0) AS TOTAL_CALL
FROM 
    dbo.tblCall_Report AR 
CROSS JOIN 
    tblRoute R 
INNER JOIN 
    tblNotification_Report BR ON R.ROUTE_ID = BR.RouteID
WHERE 
    CAST(BR.NotificationDateTime AS DATE) = '04.01.2017'
    AND BR.CallNotification = 1 
    AND (BR.NotificationStatus = 1 OR BR.NotificationStatus IS NULL)
    AND BR.RouteID IN (7434,7423)
GROUP BY 
    ROUTE_ID
```

**tblCall_Report**

```
NotificationDateTime
----------------------
2017-04-01
```

**tblNotification_Report**

```
NotificationDateTime     RouteID
--------------------------------
2017-04-01                 7434
```

Results:

```
ROUTE_ID  | TOTAL_CALL
----------+-----------
   7434   |      1
```

I want these results:

```
ROUTE_ID | TOTAL_CALL
---------+-----------
   7434  |    1    
   7423  |    0
```

Comment: Does route `7423` appear in your original data set?

Comment: yes, tim Biegeleisen

Comment: I think you probably want a LEFT OUTER JOIN in place of the INNER JOIN

Comment: Actually the where clause would make that still filter out the records - make them part of the on clause and make the where clause R.RouteID in (7434, 7423)

Comment: @JamesCasey I think you have it backwards, the `IN` condition should be moved _from_ the `WHERE` clause _to_ the `ON` clause to avoid prematurely filtering off records.

Comment: Does 7423 actually exist in the tblRoute table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and the `WHERE` clause need to be modified accordingly. Check below query

```
SELECT 
    ROUTE_ID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN BR.RouteID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL_CALL
FROM 
    dbo.tblCall_Report AR 
CROSS JOIN 
    tblRoute R 
LEFT JOIN 
    tblNotification_Report BR ON R.ROUTE_ID = BR.RouteID
    AND CAST(BR.NotificationDateTime AS DATE) = '04.01.2017'
    AND BR.CallNotification = 1 
    AND (BR.NotificationStatus = 1 OR BR.NotificationStatus IS NULL)
WHERE R.Route_ID IN (7434,7423)
GROUP BY 
    ROUTE_ID
```

Below is the result I have got.

[image]

Hope this should help you out.

Comment: Results: ROUTE_ID: 7434  | TOTAL_CALL: 1 , ROUTE_ID: 7423  | TOTAL_CALL: 1

Comment: @RızaSoylu-MaxJoffrey I have updated my answer to get proper result.

Comment: Your code assumes that there can be maximum one such row.

Comment: What is Error ? Column 'TCALL.TOTAL_CALL' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @RızaSoylu-MaxJoffrey Have you included any field in the select statement?

Comment: @RızaSoylu-MaxJoffrey In that case, kindly provide the complete sql  you are working. I notice you have provided a part of the query in comment. Post the entire query you are working in the question.

Comment: @Viki888 Can you send me your mail address ? Mail:rizasoylu06@hotmail.com

Answer (score 0):

If the route `7423` exists in your original table, then my guess is that the `INNER JOIN` is filtering off this route.  Use a `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT ROUTE_ID,
       ISNULL(COUNT(*),0) AS TOTAL_CALL
FROM dbo.tblCall_Report AR
CROSS JOIN tblRoute R
LEFT JOIN tblNotification_Report BR
    ON R.ROUTE_ID = BR.RouteID AND
       BR.RouteID IN (7434, 7423)
WHERE CAST(BR.NotificationDateTime AS DATE) = '04.01.2017' AND
      BR.CallNotification = 1 AND
      (BR.NotificationStatus =1 OR BR.NotificationStatus IS NULL)
GROUP BY ROUTE_ID
```

Comment: The result is the same.

Comment: Yay ... my first deleted answer of the day

Comment: Can you connect my computer with Teamviewer?

Comment: I updated my query per the suggestion of James Casey.  Please try it again.

Comment: The result is the same. :(

Comment: Try again...James had it backwards, the `WHERE IN` should be in the `ON` clause.

Comment: If there is no corresponding BR row, then it will have noe CallNotification, for example, hence the problem. Change the table alias in your where to R.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- use a `left join`
- move the operands using your nullable values into the `on`
- use `R` in where, as it surely has a value

  `SELECT 
      ROUTE_ID,
      CASE ISNULL(MIN(BR.RouteID), 0) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(*) END AS TOTAL_CALL
  FROM 
      dbo.tblCall_Report AR 
  CROSS JOIN 
      tblRoute R 
  LEFT JOIN 
      tblNotification_Report BR ON R.ROUTE_ID = BR.RouteID
      AND CAST(BR.NotificationDateTime AS DATE) = '04.01.2017'
      AND BR.CallNotification = 1 
      AND (BR.NotificationStatus = 1 OR BR.NotificationStatus IS NULL)
  GROUP BY 
      WHERE R.RouteID IN (7434,7423)
      ROUTE_ID`

Comment: @RızaSoylu-MaxJoffrey thank you for pointing that out. I have edited my answer to fix that.